# Kohana urls doesn't work like i need

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

So, i have this problem with urls which was bothering me for quite a while for example now i create `iframe` with `jquery` and i get my html the way i want:

```
<iframe class="iframe" src="user/upload_image" name="iframeTarget">
```

And my current url is: `user/messages/kazkoks` but for some reason when iframe loads i get error which tells me that url `user/messages/user/upload_image` was not found.

So for some reason kohana adds me `user/messages` when i don't need it, how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your current URL points relative to your `user/messages` directory, I think you should add a slash / in front of your url.

So your HTML would become:

```
<iframe class="iframe" src="/user/upload_image" name="iframeTarget">
```

EDIT: Another variant using the `url` helper:

```
<iframe class="iframe" src="<?php echo url::base().'user/upload_image'; ?>" name="iframeTarget">
```

EDIT 2: Yet another variant using JS

```
var url = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/user\/messages\/\w$/g, "/user/upload_image");
document.getElementByName("iframeTarget").setAttribute('src', url);
```

Comment: yes nothing changed and for example if i use <a href=""> in href i have to use url::base() otherwise it would create bugs when page gets more complicated

Comment: Yes it does, but i can't use it since i'm creating iframe with `js`, so i found out that i need to add folder name which is containing my website so it would be `website/user/upload_image` but what if i move my website to other host and there is no folder like that?

Comment: Hm, maybe you could pass `url::base()` as an argument to your JS function which is creating your Iframe and concatenate it with `user/upload_image` in your JS function.

Comment: yeah i guess i could do that, but now i'm thinking maybe i can use something like `window.location.pathname` i just need to get folder name (if there is any)

Comment: I think that would be a good idea. Maybe something like this: `window.location.pathname.replace(/\/user\/messages\/kozkas$/g, "/user/upload_image")`

Comment: In the end i decided to go without js and just user url::base() thanks for your help

Comment: A base tag should also be an option